# How to show JSON response in tableview according to segment in swift

Tags: json, swift, tableview, segment

I have tree segments in viewcontroller called. **`OPEN, CLOSED, ALL`**

and my JSON response is like below:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
    "data": {
        "open": [
            {
                "user_id": "10",
                "request_title": "Title-2",
                "category": "4",
                "gender": "M",
                "location": "On earth",
                "from_date": "2021-04-09",
             }
             {
            "user_id": "10",
            "request_title": "Title-2",
            "category": "4",
            "gender": "M",
            "location": "On earth",
            "from_date": "2021-04-09",
            }
            ........
            ]
        "close": [
            {
                "user_id": "10",
                "request_title": "Title-2",
                "category": "4",
                "gender": "M",
                "location": "On earth",
                "from_date": "2021-04-09",
             }
            ........
            ]
        "all": [
            {
                "user_id": "10",
                "request_title": "Title-2",
                "category": "4",
                "gender": "M",
                "location": "On earth",
                "from_date": "2021-04-09",
             }
             {
            "user_id": "10",
            "request_title": "Title-2",
            "category": "4",
            "gender": "M",
            "location": "On earth",
            "from_date": "2021-04-09",
            }
            ........
            ]
    }
}
}
```

here i am able to get JSON response.. and below `i am getting "open" values and adding them in` requestsArray`to show in tableview.. but now this`requestsArray`want to show in`open` segment  like same close values in close segment..how to do that

```
     if let code = ((resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
               
                let totalData = code["data"] as? [String : Any]
                if let open = totalData?["open"] as? [[String : Any]]{
                    for (value) in open {
                        self?.title_req = value["request_title"] as? String
                        self?.gender = value["gender"] as? String
                        self?.location = value["location"] as? String
                                                    
            self?.requestsArray.append(AppliedRequestCellData(request_title: self?.title_req, gender: self?.gender, location: self?.location))
                        
            }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }                }
```

**my segment is like below**

```
          hmSegment.indexChangeBlock = { index in
        print("in index segment")
        print(index)
        if index == 0{
          // here how to show JSON `open` response in tableview
           }

        if index == 1{
        // here how to show JSON `close` response in tableview
        }
     if index == 2{
       // here how to show JSON `all` response in tableview
     }


}
```

please help me to shoe JSON response in tableviewview with segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 4 arrays

```
var openItems = [AppliedRequestCellData]()
var closedItems = [AppliedRequestCellData]()
var allItems = [AppliedRequestCellData]()

var items = [AppliedRequestCellData]()
```

`items` is the main data source array.

Decode the data for OPEN, CLOSED and ALL and assign them to the corresponding arrays.

In `indexChangeBlock` change the contents of the main array and reload the table view

```
hmSegment.indexChangeBlock = { index in
    print("in index segment")
    switch index { 
       case 0: self.items = self.openItems
       case 1: self.items = self.closedItems
       case 2: self.items = self.allItems
       default: break
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Consider to use [`UITableViewDiffableDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource) which provides a nice animation on change.
Consider also to use `Codable` and `JSONDecoder`

Comment: thank you, one issue is.. initially at index 0 tableview is not showing.. if i go to first index and come back to index 0 then tableview is showing

Comment: i have reloaded tableview in didload as well

Comment: You have to ensure that the table view is being reloaded on the main thread.

Comment: yes in main thread only i am reloading.. but initially not showing if i move to 1st index and come to 0 index then tableview showing